# Split one row into multiple rows base on column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to split one row into multiple rows in SQL Server, based on column names. Also want to achieve this without using union multiple times.

Below is the sample input & output. Also added SQL code for input table:

[image: Click here for sample result]

```
create table T (
   Id INT, 
   A_MIN INT, 
   A_MAX INT, 
   A_VAL INT, 
   B_MIN INT, 
   B_MAX INT, 
   B_VAL INT, 
   C_MIN INT, 
   C_MAX INT, 
   C_VAL INT
)

insert into T values (4334, 25, 40, 30, 1, 9, 7, 15, 28, 9)
insert into T values (4335, 45, 48, 46, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 1)
```

Comment: please show your attempted query

Comment: Unpivot the table using `VALUES` table-value constructor and an `APPLY` operator.

Comment: Generally, search for "unpivot", and you'll find the few alternatives around

Comment: @Squirrel I tried with pivot/unpivot stuff, but it is throwing errors, so trying to write it again if there is any other way

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 6):

Unpivot the table using `VALUES` table value constructor and `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT Id, a.*
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   (A_MIN, A_MAX, A_VAL, 'A'),
   (B_MIN, B_MAX, B_VAL, 'B'),
   (C_MIN, C_MAX, C_VAL, 'C')
) a ([Min], [Max], [Val], [Type])
```